# Geokit-rails + MySQL: How to speed up search through latitude and longitude?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geokit

I have a database table that contains columns storing `latitude` and `longitude` coords (both have the `decimal` data type). The table has about 500k rows through the searches are made.

The problem is that if I search rows that are in radius of 100-200 miles, the searches lasts about 140 seconds, which is not possible to put on production.

The stack:

1. Rails 4
2. MySQL 5.5
3. [Geokit-rails gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails)

I'd like to ask you for help on how to speed up the searches through geographical data. Should I implement a search similar to [kayak.com](http://kayak.com), where are displayed some results to users and the search is still running on the background?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: 'stores' scheme**

```
  create_table "stores", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "store_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "county"
    t.string   "zip_code"
    t.decimal  "latitude",                    precision: 10, scale: 6
    t.decimal  "longitude",                   precision: 10, scale: 6
  end
```

There are no indexes on the table. I've a similar table in the database that has `latitude` and `longitude` columns too, I tried to add indexes on them, but the loading time of the searches stayed the same.

Comment: Can you please post your database schema for that table? Do you have any indexes on that table?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, `spickermann`. I added the table scheme to the OP.

Comment: check this https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-querying

Answer (score 1):

I would start with putting a combined index on the longitude and latitude columns like this:

```
class AddIndexToStoresLongitudeLatitude < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_index :stores, [:latitude, :longitude]
  end

  def down
    remove_index :stores, [:latitude, :longitude]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Best ways to solve this is using a geospatial index. However neither `geokit` nor `geocoder` do support them for relational databases. The `rgeo` gem does. It's however is not well documented. If you are doing some serios search stuff it probably will make sense to delegate this problem to elastic_search.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, `dre-hh`. I'll take a look on `elastic_search` closer. Speaking about the geospatial index, I found this - https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-mysqlspatial-adapter - gem, wondering if it's worth to play with as it's pretty outdated.

Comment: I'm actually not aware of anyone solving this problem with relational databases. Only hear from folks solving this by using mongo or elastic_search

Answer (score 0):

If @spickermann answer won't work, IMO you should migrate to Postgres. PostGis is a very powerfull tool with great performance. http://postgis.net/